# java:comp/UserTransaction is not bound in the context using btm and spring

Tags: spring, tomcat, transactions

I am trying to configure bitronix as my JTA manager with spring like this:

```
<!--  Bitronix Transaction Manager embedded configuration -->
    <bean id="xaDataSource" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource"
        init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="className" value="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.lrc.LrcXADataSource" />
        <property name="uniqueName" value="java/DS1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="0" />
        <property name="allowLocalTransactions" value="false" />
        <property name="testQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
        <property name="driverProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="user">user</prop>
                <prop key="password">user</prop>
                <prop key="url">url</prop>
                <prop key="driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="btmConfig" factory-method="getConfiguration"
        class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices">
        <property name="serverId" value="spring-btm" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="bitronixTransactionManager" factory-method="getTransactionManager"
        class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices" depends-on="btmConfig,xaDataSource"
        destroy-method="shutdown" />


    <bean id="jtaTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="bitronixTransactionManager" />
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="bitronixTransactionManager" />
    </bean>
    <!--  end of Bitronix Transaction Manager embedded configuration -->
```

I see that bitronix is starting and running:

```
399 DEBUG (        PoolingDataSource.java:84)     - building XA pool for java/DS1 with 0 connection(s) etc..)
```

However when I try:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
```

I get naming exception for it.

WHy is it? what else do I need to configure?

**EDITED**

I saw in [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Transaction) that the `<Transaction>` can bound the transaction manager to take care of it.

wouldn't it be a conflict that I define it both in tomcat and in spring?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your web app's META-INF/context.xml:

```
<Context>
  <Transaction factory="bitronix.tm.BitronixUserTransactionObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

This should bind the transaction manager under the java:comp/UserTransaction name for this particular web app only.